# Search in Android calendar Instances

Tags: android, calendar

I want to search events in Android Calendar API `Instances` table by title or description. But I can't fetch all instances from the table because of API. `CalendarContract.Instances` has `CONTENT_SEARCH_URI`. Does anybody know how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is `CONTENT_SEARCH_URI` and how to use it.

`CONTENT_SEARCH_URI` = `content://com.android.calendar/instances/search`

If you want to use it, add 3 arguments: `begin` in millis, `end` in millis and `search` as String.

```
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_SEARCH_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath(Long.toString(startDate));
builder.appendPath(Long.toString(endDate));
builder.appendPath(searchString);
Uri uri = builder.build();
```

The path will be `content://com.android.calendar/instances/search/[your begin]/[your end]/[your search]`

If you make query with this `Uri`, Android makes this SQL:

```
SELECT Instances._id AS _id, Instances.event_id AS event_id,
    title, description, eventLocation
FROM (Instances INNER JOIN view_events AS Events ON
        (Instances.event_id=Events._id))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Attendees ON (Attendees.event_id=Events._id)
WHERE (begin<=? AND end>=?)
GROUP BY Instances._id
HAVING (title LIKE ? ESCAPE "#"
    OR description LIKE ? ESCAPE "#"
    OR eventLocation LIKE ? ESCAPE "#"
    OR group_concat(attendeeEmail) LIKE ? ESCAPE "#"
    OR group_concat(attendeeName) LIKE ? ESCAPE "#" )
```